# vue.js + android keyboard - the last typed word is missing on the model

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, input, dom-events

I am trying to debug a strange problem:

```
<textarea v-model='val' @input='test'></textarea> <div> {{val}}</div> <div>{{log}}</div>'
<script>
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app", template: "#template", data: { val:"" ,log:""},
    methods: {
        test() {
            this.log += "."
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

on  Android,  when Virtual keyboard Autosuggest is enabled, the  `val` variable did not updated on typing, until the user will press a space key, or clicked the Autosuggested word, or blur the textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is mainly the `input` event, that did not fired on typing when the autocorrect is on. This is broke the `v-model` so the underlying model is not updating on this case.

Workarounds:

1. remove the `v-model`, and direct binding to the `keydown` event

   ```
   <textarea  v-model="text"  ref="textarea" autocomplete="off"  @keydown="test" ></textarea>
   ```

   as the `value` is updated *after* the `keydown` event, we need to track it manualy via `setTimeout`  and 1ms.

   ```
   var vm=this; 
   setTimeout(function () { 
      vm.val = vm.$refs.textarea.value; 
      vm.$emit('input', vm.val);  // for components compatibility with v-model
   }, 1);
   ```
2. add a   `autocorrect="off"` to the textarea. this will hide the autocorrect from the keyboard so the problem will solved.

Answer (score 2):

For those still coming across this problem, binding to the `keydown` event or turning off autocorrect may not be necessary. Since

```
v-model="example"
```

is just syntactic sugar, it can be expanded out to

```
:value="example" @input="example= $event.target.value"
```

I had the exact same problem with Android and autocorrect, and this solved it for me. This may possibly be a bug with Vue 2, since it supposedly worked fine in Vue 1. See the discussion here https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8231

Comment: nice ! you was descibed the same problem but better then me. see also this:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8007